# How to generate kafka key with mongoID in MongoDB Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, mongodb-kafka-connector

So i want create mongodb source connector and elasticsearch sink connector, the problem is i can't find right configuration for mongodb source connector or elasticsearch sink connector got connected. FYI, im using **io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector** and **com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector**

MongoDB Source Connector

```
{
    "name": "ais-mongodb-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
        "publish.full.document.only": "true",
        "database": "ais-user",
        "output.json.formatter": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson",
        "offset.partition.name": "ais-user.1",
        "output.format.value": "json",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.uri": "",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup"
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch Sink Connector

```
{
    "name": "ais-es-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "type.name": "_doc",
        "topics": "ais-user.administrator",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "key.ignore": "true",
        "schema.ignore": "true",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "name": "ais-es-sink-connector",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "connection.url": "http://es01:9200",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
    }
}
```

I got this error

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Indexing record failed -> Response status: BAD_REQUEST,\n Index: ais-user.administrator,\n Document Id: ais-user.administrator+0+12
```

I think this is caused by index on elasticsearch

I want publish key using mongoID format, so i use transform but got an error somekind of **Only MAP Supported**

Comment: For that error, you can add `"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"` to force JSON data into a map schema. You may need to do the same for the key converter. Otherwise, use StringConverter for elastic key setting as well

Comment: In any case, please share an example of your data in the topic as well as your elastic index definition with an [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im using `output.format.key` to publish mongoID as a key in kafka topic:

```
"output.format.key": "schema",
"output.schema.key": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"keySchema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"documentKey._id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To write exactly Mongo key as Kafka topic key you will need to add one more step to the answer of Difa Al:

```
        "transforms": "id",
        "transforms.id.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.id.field": "documentKey._id",
```